# MySQL JOIN statement

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables like below:

#### product_name

```
 id | productName
----+-----------------
  1 | item 1
  2 | item 2
  3 | item 3
```

#### exchange_history

```
 id | exchangeFrom | exchangeTo
----+--------------+------------
  1 |            1 |          3
  2 |            3 |          2
  3 |            2 |          1
```

I have to create a query like `SELECT * from exchange_history`, but I have to replace the `id` of the columns `exchangeFrom` and `exchangeTo` to actually display the corresponding `name` according to the `product_name` table.

The output should look like this:

```
  "id":"1","exchangeFrom":"item 1","exchangeTo":"item 3"
  "id":"2","exchangeFrom":"item 3","exchangeTo":"item 2"
  "id":"3","exchangeFrom":"item 2","exchangeTo":"item 1"
```

How can I achieve this? I tried to use inner join/left join and for one column it was OK, but when I tried for 2 columns it's not working.

Comment: You'll need to join with `product_name` twice.

Comment: I need a bit more explained because I am not experienced with this,would you plz write a sample code for given data plz that will be very helpfull for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below

```
create table product_name (
   id           smallint,
   productname  varchar(10)
);

create table exchange_history (
   id           smallint,
   exchangeFrom smallint,
   exchangeTo   smallint
);

insert into product_name values (1, 'item 1');
insert into product_name values (2, 'item 2');
insert into product_name values (3, 'item 3');

insert into exchange_history values (1,1,3);
insert into exchange_history values (2,3,2);
insert into exchange_history values (3,2,1);


select h.id,
       p.productname  as exchangeFrom,
       p1.productname as exchangeTo
 from exchange_history h
 join product_name p
   on h.exchangeFrom = p.id
 join product_name p1
  on h.exchangeTo = p1.id
```

See here

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uyQUzwwGf39MV46Df28PWa/0

Comment: I am looking for mysql

Comment: It works, tnx a lot!